# Bootstrap Datepicker - Disable dates - Multiple datepickers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

i'm using a bootstrap plugin for the datepicker (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/).
When you go to the link above there's a code example for how you can make an easy check-in check-out form. On the check-out datepicker all dates previous to the check-in datepicker are disabled.

On my site there are multiple checkin-checkout forms (for multiple rooms). Per room you have a check-in and a check-out datepicker (couples). So i figured the following code would do it.

Create an array with all the datepickers found on the page (it can be variable). Then loop through the array per 2 + apply code per couple.

```
if ($('.datepicker').length) { 
//get all the datepickers
var IDs = [];
$(".main").find(".datepicker").each(function(){ IDs.push(this.id); });

for(j=0;j<IDs.length;j++){
    var nowTemp = new Date();
        var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

        var checkin = $('#'+ IDs[j]).datepicker({
        onRender: function(date) {
                 return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        }
        }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
        var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
        checkout.setValue(newDate);
        checkin.hide();
        $('#'+ IDs[j+1])[0].focus();
        }).data('datepicker');

        var checkout = $('#'+ IDs[j+1]).datepicker({
        onRender: function(date) {
            return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        }
        }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
        checkout.hide();
        }).data('datepicker');
    j++;
    }
}
```

The outcoume is that if I have 2 datepickers on the page the second one works as expected. The first one not at all. If i have 1 datepicker on the page it works.

When adding alert(IDs) i get an array with the ID's in the correct order as wanted.

If anyone can help... :) thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this and thought I would post the answer in case anyone is looking.

It works by looking for anything with class 'datepicker'. If that item has an ID ending with 'from', it looks for the corresponding item with an ID ending with 'to'. If the ID doesn't end with 'from' or 'to', it binds an ordinary datepicker.

I am sure a jquery guru could do better ;-)

External JS:

```
function datepickerFromTo(fromSelector, toSelector, format) {
    var nowTemp = new Date();
    var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

    var fromDate = $(fromSelector).datepicker({
        weekStart: 1,
        format: format,
        onRender: function (date) {
            return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        }
    }).on('show', function (ev) {
        toDate.hide();
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        if (ev.date.valueOf() > toDate.date.valueOf()) {
            var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
            newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate());
            toDate.setValue(newDate);
        }
        fromDate.hide();
        $(toSelector)[0].focus();
    }).data('datepicker');

    var toDate = $(toSelector).datepicker({
        weekStart: 1,
        format: format,
        onRender: function (date) {
            return date.valueOf() <= fromDate.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        }
    }).on('show', function (ev) {
        fromDate.hide();
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        toDate.hide();
    }).data('datepicker');
}
```

At bottom of page:

```
<script>
$('.datepicker').each(function() {
    var thisId = $(this).attr("id");

    if(thisId.length >= 4 && thisId.substr(thisId.length - 4) == "from") { // The ID ends with 'from' - treat it as a 'from' date
        var idRoot = thisId.substr(0, thisId.length - 4);
        var toDateSelector = '#' + idRoot + 'to';
        var toDate = $(toDateSelector);
        if(toDate.length) { // Found a matching 'to date'
            datepickerFromTo('#' + thisId,toDateSelector,'dd/mm/yyyy');
        }
    } else if(!thisId.length >= 2 && thisId.substr(thisId.length - 2) == "to") { // Bind an ordinary datepicker. Exclude anything with ID ending with 'to' date as this is handled when binding 'from' date.
        $(this).datepicker({
            weekStart: 1,
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
        });
    }
});
</script>
```